# Pointers and sorting

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, pointers, tree

I have a problem where I use pointers to point to an array of structs. It works perfectly well, but I need to add to this array and re-sort it on every pass, because of this my pointers will effectively change which characters they're pointing to as they're pointing to the same array index.

Is there any way I can get around this? I've been trying with another array, but I still have the problem where I need to insert new element to the existing array and re-sort it.

Comment: instead of sorting the structs, sort the array of pointers according to values in the structs. For insertions, do a binary search into the array of pointers, then shift all "higher" pointers up by one to create an empty slot for the new pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using an array of structs, you can use an array of pointers to structs, individually allocating the struct instances.  Then you can sort the array of pointers without changing the addresses of any of the structs it points to.  That way, pointers to the structs will remain valid.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a go, great idea.

Comment: How would I go about creating an array of pointers that point to an array of structures? Element by element, just been trying it and I can't do it :/

Comment: Allocate the array of pointers.  Then iterate over each pointer in the array, allocating a struct and storing its address at that array position.  You can use `malloc` for both the array and the structs.  If you later need to grow the array, you can use `realloc`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array of structs then sorting that array implies moving its elements around in memory, except if the array starts out already in order.  If you move an object then you inherently invalidate any existing pointers to it.  If that is not evident to you, then meditate on what a pointer is and what moving an object means.

One alternative would be to maintain and sort an array of pointers to your structs, instead of sorting the structs themselves.  In that case you would be moving only the pointers, not the things they point to, therefore the pointers to your structs would not be invalidated.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a go, great idea.

Comment: How would I go about creating an array of pointers that point to an array of structures? Element by element, just been trying it and I can't do it :/